# Change GET to POST request in 'sort' of tables2

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-tables2

I need to have a sorting request back to my template page in the POST request form, but the sort of the column provide by `django-tables2` give  a GET request form like that :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mypage?sort=mycolumn
```

## mytemplate.html

```
 <form
    id="test"
    action="{% url 'myview' %}"
    method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    #somes buttons and filters

    <div
        class="row"
        style=" white-space: nowrap; top: 950px;">

        <div class="form-group col-lg-7 center">

        {% load django_tables2 %} {% render_table table %} <br />


            </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

How transform this 'sort' in POST request instead of the GET request ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

django-tables2 uses links (in `<a>` tags) to manipulate sorting. If you want to change that to POST, you would have to change the template to replace the `<a>` tags used for sorting with some way to submit the same information as a POST request. If that's done, `RequestConfig` should be changed to look in POST [where it currently looks in GET](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/0b3f150e1d0d37ca1e2249f8366c4f7c8b3a6ea4/django_tables2/config.py#L38)

I am curious *why* you want to transform this into POST data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that it's a little tricky to done this change for me :/ I want have POST data request because i use filter (POST formular) above the tables2 table and when i want use the filter i lost the sorting of the columns and vice versa....

Comment: Why not use GET for the filters as well?

Comment: I dont want send information by URL. It's more secure and friendly for the user... if i have no 'easy' solution (i dont want edit tables2) maybe i will be use GET request for my filters --'